# Loading html template into div based on element selection inside of that div(same elements across all divs)

Tags: jquery

Having issues loading templates into already existing divs based on selections made within a child of the div being replaced. You will see roster01, roster02 & roster03 WHICH SHOULD ALWAYS REMAIN THE SAME. Inside of those rosters, you will see div classes `'item01'`, `'item02'`, `'item03'`. For this example, imagine these contents sitting inside of their own html templates(temp01.html, temp02.html, temp03.html).

Basically, I'm trying to make it to where each roster utilizes the same options(item01, item02, item03) that a user clicks and based on the option selected replaces the closest roster class with the templates content.

I can get one template to load with my code below, but it doesn't replace the roster, it just inserts the code inside of the already existing one.

Here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
    //
    // HIDDEN ELEMENTS THAT DON'T LOAD WITH TEMPLATE
    // 
    $('.hiddenOnLoad').hide();
});

$('#roster01, #roster02, #roster03').on('click', '.h01, .h02, .h03', function(e){
 $('.h01').on("click", "a", function (e) {
    $($(this)).closest('.roster').load('templates/hero/temp01.html');
  });
  $('.h02').on("click", "a", function (e) {
    $($(this)).closest('.roster').load('templates/hero/temp02.html');
  });
  $('.h03').on("click", "a", function (e) {
    $($(this)).closest('.roster').load('templates/hero/temp03.html');
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
}
.item01 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.item02 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #555;
}
.item03 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc">
  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster01">
  
    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp01.html -->
    <div class="item01">
      <div>
       <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
       <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
       <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hiddenOnLoad">
      <!-- This is an example of a hidden element within the item class that is hidden on document.ready and shows as visible when new template loads -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster02">
 
    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp02.html -->
    <div class="item02">
      <div>
        <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
        <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
        <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hiddenOnLoad">
      <!-- This is an example of a hidden element within the item class that is hidden on document.ready and shows as visible when new template loads -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster03">
    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp03.html -->
    <div class="item03">
      <div>
       <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
       <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
       <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hiddenOnLoad">
      <!-- This is an example of a hidden element within the item class that is hidden on document.ready and shows as visible when new template loads -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand this 100% but is this the effect you are going for? Having the click event inside a click event is not a great idea so I took that part out. Play around with my example and see if that is what you are trying to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.hiddenOnLoad').hide();

  $("#hideMe").on("click", function() {
    $("body .hiddenOnLoad").hide();
  });
  
   $("#showMe").on("click", function() {
    $("body .hiddenOnLoad").show();
  });

  /* just some data for testing */
  var temp01 = "<div class='item01'><div><a class='h01' href='#'>Item 01 </a><a class='h02' href='#'>Item 02 </a><a class='h03' href='#'>Item 03</a></div><div class='hiddenOnLoad'>test1</div></div></div>";
  var temp02 = "<div class='item02'><div><a class='h01' href='#'>Item 01 </a><a class='h02' href='#'>Item 02 </a><a class='h03' href='#'>Item 03</a></div><div class='hiddenOnLoad'>test2</div></div></div>";
  var temp03 = "<div class='item03'><div><a class='h01' href='#'>Item 01 </a><a class='h02' href='#'>Item 02 </a><a class='h03' href='#'>Item 03</a></div><div class='hiddenOnLoad'>test3</div></div></div>";


  //$('#roster01, #roster02, #roster03').on('click', '.h01, .h02, .h03', function(e) {}); // removed this for testing 
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------
  var focusOnMe1 = "#roster01 .h01, #roster02 .h01, #roster03 .h01";
  var focusOnMe2 = "#roster01 .h02, #roster02 .h02, #roster03 .h02";
  var focusOnMe3 = "#roster01 .h03, #roster02 .h03, #roster03 .h03";

  $('body').on("click", focusOnMe1, function(e) {
    $($(this)).closest('.roster').html(temp01); // just for test data
    //$($(this)).closest('.roster').load('templates/hero/temp01.html');    
  });
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------   
  $('body').on("click", focusOnMe2, function(e) {
    $($(this)).closest('.roster').html(temp02); // just for test data
    //$($(this)).closest('.roster').load('templates/hero/temp02.html');
  });
  // -------------------------------------------------------------------  
  $('body').on("click", focusOnMe3, function(e) {
    $($(this)).closest('.roster').html(temp03); // just for test data
    //$($(this)).closest('.roster').load('templates/hero/temp03.html');
  });

});
```

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
}

.item01 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.item02 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #555;
}

.item03 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="hideMe">Hide ME</button>
<button id="showMe">Show ME</button>

<div class="calc">
  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster01">

    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp01.html -->
    <div class="item01">
      <div>
        <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
        <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
        <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hiddenOnLoad">
        test1
        <!-- This is an example of a hidden element within the item class that is hidden on document.ready and shows as visible when new template loads -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster02">

    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp02.html -->
    <div class="item02">
      <div>
        <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
        <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
        <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hiddenOnLoad">
        test2
        <!-- This is an example of a hidden element within the item class that is hidden on document.ready and shows as visible when new template loads -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster03">
    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp03.html -->
    <div class="item03">
      <div>
        <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
        <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
        <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
      <div class="hiddenOnLoad">
        test3
        <!-- This is an example of a hidden element within the item class that is hidden on document.ready and shows as visible when new template loads -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes!! I think so! Let me go ahead and test on my actual code and get back to you. I guess I was pretty close. I will update as soon as I can if this is the solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, so this definitely works.. BUT... my template loads overtop of my other roster. So essentially the code looks like this:

`<div class="roster">

<!-- THIS IS THE TEMPLATE THAT LOADS -->
   <div class="roster">
   </div>
</div>`

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck.

Comment: sorry to bother after the fact. I realized though, I have document.ready elements that are hidden in each item class that when the template loads, are no longer hidden. How do I fix that issue? I tried doing 

`$('#roster01, #roster02, #roster03').on("click", ".h02", function(e) {
  $($(this)).closest('.roster').load('templates/hero/temp02.html');
  $('.hiddenelementondocument.ready).hide();
}); `

But this doesn't hide the elements on template load =[.

Comment: Ok, that is because the element was not loaded in before the js so, instead of focusing on the #roster01, #roster02, #roster03, have it focus on a container that is always visible, like the body. I have edited the above answer so you can see what i mean. If the .calc class wrapper div you have there is always visible you could use that instead of body. So, $("body").on("click", ".classThatMayBeHidden", function(){ // some action});

Comment: Dude, you are an expert.

Comment: Sorry.. I spoke too soon. This doesn't seem to resolve the issue. First of all, thank you so much for helping me with this as I have been so stuck it's been unreal. The templates load perfectly, so thank you.

To better explain this new issue, I have edited my HTML above to show what exactly is hidden on document.ready and how it isn't hidden even after this change. It just shows as visible on new template load.

Comment: Ok, I tested it in the above code(added the hidden elements) and it seems to work. It will select the hidden elements even if they are hidden on load. My guess is, looking at your code up top, is that you only put the $('.hiddenOnLoad').hide(); inside the $(document).ready(function() {});. The other on click things need to go inside that on document ready function too. Check how I wrote it up above. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148807/discussion-between-dbrree-and-icewine).

Answer (score 1):

First of... A `click` handler within a `click` handler is a bad thing.

Then, you could use the anchor's `class`, which looks to be numbered similarly to the template to be loaded.

```
$('#roster01, #roster02, #roster03').on('click', '.h01, .h02, .h03', function(e){

  // Deduct the template number from the clicked anchor class
  var templateNumber = $(this).attr("class").substr(-2);  // Returns 01 or 02 or 03

  // Use the number found in the URL to load.
  $(this).closest('.roster').load('templates/hero/temp'+templateNumber+'.html');
});
```

It worths a try!
;)

Comment: Thanks for sharing best practice with me. Let me give it a try and see what happens! Ohh also, what if I end up changing the actual template names(which I most likely will) to indivdual words. For example, red, blue or black(not that will be it, but they won't have #'s associated later).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my other answer,
If you wanted to just changed the class template depending on the item you clicked you could simply do this. That way you would not need to load anything. Only adding or removing classes. Of course it all depends on what your end goal would be. Just for your information in any case.

```js
$('#roster01, #roster02, #roster03').on("click", "a", function(e) {

  $(this).closest('.roster').children("div").removeClass(); // clear current class and then add the new class depending on what item was clicked.

  switch ($(this).attr("class")) {
    case "h01":
      $(this).closest('.roster').children("div").addClass("item01");
      break;
    case "h02":
      $(this).closest('.roster').children("div").addClass("item02");
      break;
    case "h03":
      $(this).closest('.roster').children("div").addClass("item03");
      break;
  }

});
```

```css
a {
  color: #fff;
}

.item01 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.item02 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #555;
}

.item03 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="calc">
  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster01">

    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp01.html -->
    <div class="item01">
      <div>
        <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
        <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
        <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster02">

    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp02.html -->
    <div class="item02">
      <div>
        <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
        <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
        <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ROSTERS NEVER CHANGE JUST LOAD THE ITEM INFORMATION BASED ON THE TEMPLATE -->
  <div class="roster" id="roster03">
    <!-- IMAGINE THIS CODE AS THE TEMPLATE IN /temp03.html -->
    <div class="item03">
      <div>
        <a class="h01" href="#">Item 01</a>
        <a class="h02" href="#">Item 02</a>
        <a class="h03" href="#">Item 03</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```